# Laravel create and change database in the same request

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, schema

What I want to do is create a database with a request from the form.

Then connect to the database created and create a table inside.

on the same page and on the same request.

I do not know what to do because the env file and the database file are used when the page is opened and I can not enter values there.

```
$database_create_control=DB::statement('create database '.$prefix);
```

/*****/

```
  Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('company_id');
      $table->string('company_name',255);
      $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
      $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
  });
```

the table I am connecting to is occurring in the database

but my wish was to work in the database I created a few lines ago.

Comment: have a table that holds databases information and use it when you need?

Comment: The database I want to use is ***DB::statement('create database '.$prefix);** the database . I created with this database in the code.

But this database is not defined in the '.env' and 'config/database.php' files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the database this is how you connect to it:

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
"host" => "...",
"database" => "...",
"username" => "...",
"password" => "...
]);
```

then do `DB::purge('mysql');`

then right after this do `Schema::create('companies')`... so you could use the new db

Comment: but it does not occur in the database I created the table again. It occurs in the current database.

Comment: after you do this the config is set to use this connection in every request, so you can use it like normal

Comment: what do you mean by `formed` ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'companies' already exists (SQL: create table `companies` (`company_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `company_name` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' engine = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC)

Comment: database connection is not change

Answer (score 0):

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql', array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => $prefix,
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ));
        // and reconnect the DB class to the newly created version.

        DB::reconnect();
```

this solution is work ! thanks @Hussein